# Swing JTextArea multithreading problem - InterruptedException

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

I have a simple console application that runs calculations in several threads (10-20 of them). Now I'm trying to create a simple GUI that allows me to select the file to process and prints logs from all threads.

So, I created a swing GUI with JTextArea for my log and a method to log information to the log:

```
public synchronized void log(String text) {
    logArea.append(text);
    logArea.append("\n");

    if (logArea.getDocument().getLength() > 50000) {
        try {
            logArea.getDocument().remove(0,5000);
        } catch (BadLocationException e) {
            log.error("Can't clean log", e);
        }
    }

    logArea.setCaretPosition(logArea.getDocument().getLength());
}
```

However, the `setCaretPosition` method sometimes deadlocks on waiting some lock, and `append` sometimes throws InterruptedException.

```
Exception in thread "Thread-401" java.lang.Error: Interrupted attempt to aquire write lock
at javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument.writeLock(AbstractDocument.java:1334)
at javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument.insertString(AbstractDocument.java:687)
at javax.swing.text.PlainDocument.insertString(PlainDocument.java:114)
at javax.swing.JTextArea.append(JTextArea.java:470)
at lt.quarko.aquila.scripts.ui.ScriptSessionFrame.log(ScriptSessionFrame.java:215)
```

I'm a total newbie in Swing, so I can not understand what am I doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't want to manipulate Swing objects directly from another thread, you want to [post manipulations to its event queue](http://www.kauss.org/Stephan/swing/index.html).

Comment: This still does not solve the deadlock problem when dealing with high frequency updates.  See my solution below.

Answer (score 3):

You should not update ui component from other threads, you should use EventDispatchThread. Here is the solution ;

```
 public synchronized void log(String text) {
        Runnable  runnable = new Runnable() {
            public void run(){
                logArea.append(text);
                logArea.append("\n");
                if (logArea.getDocument().getLength() > 50000) {
                    try {
                        logArea.getDocument().remove(0, 5000);
                    } catch (BadLocationException e) {
                        log.error("Can't clean log", e);
                    }
                }
                logArea.setCaretPosition(logArea.getDocument().getLength());
            }
        }
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(runnable);

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Max, you didn't mention, that you `interrupt` the thread. But you surely did. So your question consists actually of 2 separate questions.

> `append` sometimes throws InterruptedException

I just fell into the same situation and don't know how to handle it. When I interrupt the thread, then `Document.insertString` fails throwing this kind of error.

Others are not quite right about putting all in EDT thread. [`JTextArea.append`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#append%28java.lang.String%29) method is thread safe, so it needn't be wrapped. The only method you call that you should not (in work thread) is `setCaretPosition`. So why you accept the `invokeLater` answer? Probably because putting document access in one thread removed all locking problems. See `AbstractDocument.writeLock` [open jdk code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/javax/swing/text/AbstractDocument.java#AbstractDocument.writeLock%28%29), that explains a bit this `Error`.

So it looks like putting `Document` writes in EDT thread is really necessary, but only when one wants to interrupt the thread. And as a workaround for pretty unkind `AbstractDocument` behaviour, that throws an `Error` in this case.

I came up with the following workaround for `Document` `Error`. It's not quite clean, because the thread may be unfortunately interrupted right after setting `bInterrupted` flag. But this may be avoided by performing `Thread.interrupt()` in a controlled, synchronized way.

```
// test the flag and clear it (interrupted() method does clear it)
boolean bInterrupted = Thread.interrupted();
m_doc.insertString(m_doc.getLength(), s, null);
// restore the original interrupted state
if (bInterrupted)
  Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
```

> `setCaretPosition` method sometimes deadlocks on waiting some lock

Here is my solution for caret update. I could simply go with `invokeLater`, but I wanted to avoid superfluous calls, so I added an additional flag:

```
/** <code>true</code> when gui update scheduled. This flag is to avoid
  * multiple overlapping updates, not to call
  * <code>invokeLater</code> too frequently.
 */
private volatile boolean m_bUpdScheduled;

/** Updates output window so that the last line be visible */
protected void update()
{
  if (!m_bUpdScheduled) {
    m_bUpdScheduled = true;
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
          m_bUpdScheduled = false;
          try {
            m_ebOut.setCaretPosition(m_doc.getLength());
          }
          catch (IllegalArgumentException iae) {
            // doc not in sync with text field - too bad
          }
        }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: _JTextArea.append method is thread safe_ repeating a myth that even the swing devs fell for :-) That's not true - see the latest jdk 7 api doc - and never was (though debated a lot and heatedly).

Comment: @kleopatra, thanks for pointing that out. However `AbstractDocument.insertString` is thread safe both in jdk 6 and 7. See my answer [there](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12769616/772981) for details.

Comment: FYI, you can still get deadlock for high-frequency updates. See my solution below on how to avoid or mitigate the deadlock problem.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but using the setCaretPosition() method for auto-scrolling the viewport to the bottom can lead to a deadlock problem if the frequency of updates to the JTextArea is very high. Having the updates only done on the EDT did not avoid the problem or provide any improvement.

Ways to avoid the problem:

- Do not attempt to auto-scroll, and set the caret update policy to NEVER_UPDATE.  Likely not ideal, but in our main application, we have a "scroll lock" capability so output can be viewed while text is still being captured.
- Throttle the use of setCaretPosition(): If dealing with high volume of updates, set the caret after X number of updates.  I have our application track diagnostics by lines, so I can defer the caret update each time until X number of lines are captured.  Note, you still need to set caret update policy to NEVER_UPDATE if throttling.
- If your JTextArea is in a JScrollPane, then use the vertical scrollbar directly and reposition it to maximum position after each update to the text area.  Make sure to use invokeLater() when repositioning the scrollbar so any size change that occurred due to text addition is taken into consideration.

The following is code fragment of a class I created for capturing text into a JTextComponent (or subclass thereof) that checks if scroll pane method is in effect:

```
  if (autoScroll && (scrollPane != null)) {
    final JScrollBar vertical = scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar();
    if (vertical != null) {
      appendText(doc, txt);
      java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override public void run() {
          vertical.setValue(vertical.getMaximum());
        }
      });
      return;
    }
  }
```

If scroll pane is not available, then the caret-method is used, where throttling can be specified to minimize the risk of deadlock inside of swing code.