# JTextArea thread safe?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, user-interface, jtextarea

I have some code that does some initialization (including making a `JTextArea` object), starts three separate threads, and then these threads try to update the `JTextArea` (i.e. `append()` to it), but its not working at all. Nothing shows up on the `JTextArea` (however, during the initialization, I print some test lines onto it, and that works fine). What's going on? How can I fix this? Also, each of those threads sleeps a random amount of time every time it has to update the `JTextArea`.

Sorry I haven't provided any code, its all spread out over several files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although I believe the API has stated that JTextArea#append(...) is thread safe, I've heard of problems with it and would recommend that this only be called on the EDT.  The classic example of this is to use a SwingWorker and append to the JTextArea in the process method by calling publish.

For me, it'll be hard to make any specific suggestions to you though without code.  I do have to wonder though if you're putting the EDT to sleep somewhere in your code.

Edit: as per your comment check out this tutorial: [Concurrency in Swing](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)

---

Edit 2: as per comment by [Tim Perry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/287530/tim-perry), loss of thread safety and the reasoning behind this has been posted in [this Java bug](http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=4765383) and which has to do with this line of code where text is added to the JTextArea's Document:

```
doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), str, null);
```

The line decomposes into two lines:

1. `int len=doc.getLength();`
2. `doc.insertString(len,str,null);`

The issue is that a problem can occur if the Document, doc, changes between lines 1 and 2, especially the Document length.

Comment: +1 Agree. I see the thread-safe _proviso_ for some `JTextArea` methods in previous versions has been dropped in J2SE 7. http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html

Comment: http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=4765383 explains why it is no longer listed as threadsafe

Comment: @TimPerry: Thank you for the update. I've incorporated your information into my answer.

Answer (score 3):

In Java 1.6, the documentation for `JTextArea.append` says:

> Appends the given text to the end of
>   the document. Does nothing if the
>   model is null or the string is null or
>   empty.
>
> This method is thread safe,
>   although most Swing methods are not.
>   Please see How to Use Threads for more
>   information.

In JDK7 the second part is missing:

> Appends the given text to the end of
>   the document. Does nothing if the
>   model is null or the string is null or
>   empty.

If you look at the `Document` interface (which `JTextArea` can use a user supplied instance), there is no way to append text in a thread-safe manner even if the implementation is thread-safe. Swing threading is just broken. I strongly suggest sticking rigidly to the AWT EDT when going anywhere near Swing components.

Comment: I had problems with understanding this: *there is no way to append text in a thread-safe manner even if the implementation is thread-safe*, so I'll try to elaborate on it. I guess you mean: there is no atomic *append* operation in Document interface, so to append one must actually perform 2 subsequent calls: `getLength`, `insertString`. There is no way to guarantee that the contents doesn't change between these 2 calls.

Answer (score 2):

[`JTextArea.append(..)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#append%28java.lang.String%29) is thread safe so it should be safe to call it from different threads.

However the javadoc of `.append()` states:

```
Does nothing if the model is null or the string is null or empty.
```

So, make sure that the model of JTextArea is initialized (via appropriate constructor).

Answer (score 2):

I trust experienced guys who warn about believing in `Document`'s thread safety. However it's hard to believe that an application exploits this problem so easily resulting in `JTextArea` displaying nothing at all. Maybe some other methods are used except `append` and they cause general failure. I attach a testing app, that I run on Debian with Oracle jre 6 (and also Win7 with java 6 64bit) and see no problems.

During the development process I had to fix several mistakes which included:

1. Not synchronizing `getLength()` and `insertString()` method which resulted in wrong insertion placement and even `BadLocationException`s. Other threads were modifying the document between these 2 instructions. Even if they were on the same line :)
2. Swallowing `BadLocationException`. I was sure it's impossible to hit it, but was wrong.

After realizing the above, especially the need of creating a critical section for `getLength()` and `insertString()` pair, it's obvious that `JTextArea` would fail ([see Tom Hawtin's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4873998/772981)). And I saw it actually did, because not every `insertString` was executed successfully and the resulting text was shorter than it should be. However this problem did not occur with loop count 10000, only at 100000. And looking into [jdk 7 code of JTextArea.append](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/javax/swing/JTextArea.java#JTextArea.append%28java.lang.String%29), which does nothing but modify the underlying document, it seems that synchronizing `JTextArea` externally would also do.

Inserting at 0 also worked well, without any synchronization, although it took ages to complete.

Usually in such applications one wants to scroll to the last line. Hey, this is awt. You can't `setCaretPosition` out of EDT. So I don't. Scroll manually. My suggestion to solve scrolling is in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12767568/772981).

If you guys see problems with this application on your system, please comment. My conclusion is that **`Document.insertString` is thread safe, however to use it effectively, together with `getLength`, synchronization is neccessary.**

In the following code `PlainDocument` is subclassed to create synchronized `append` method, which wraps `getLength` and `insertString` into a lock. This lock has protected access, so I couldn't use it without a separate class. However external synchronization also gave correct results.

*BTW: Sorry for so many edits. Finally I restructured this answer after learning more.*

The code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;

class SafePlainDocument extends PlainDocument
{
  public void append(String s)
  {
    writeLock();
    try {
      insertString(getLength(), s,  null);
    }
    catch (BadLocationException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
      writeUnlock();
    }
  }
}

public class StressJText
{
  public static CountDownLatch m_latch;
  public static SafePlainDocument m_doc;
  public static JTextArea m_ta;

  static class MyThread extends Thread
  {
    SafePlainDocument m_doc;
    JTextArea m_ta;

    public MyThread(SafePlainDocument doc)
    {
      m_doc = doc;
    }

    public void run() 
    {
      for (int i=1; i<=100000; i++) {
        String s = String.format("%19s %9d\n", getName(), i);
        m_doc.append(s);
      }
      StressJText.m_latch.countDown();
    }
  }

  public static void main(String sArgs[])
  {
    System.out.println("hello");
    final int cThreads = 5;
    m_latch = new CountDownLatch(cThreads);
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
          JFrame frame = new JFrame();
          m_ta = new JTextArea();
          m_doc = new SafePlainDocument();
          m_ta.setDocument(m_doc);
          m_ta.setColumns(50);
          m_ta.setRows(20);
          JScrollPane scrollPane = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
          scrollPane.setViewportView(m_ta);
          frame.add(scrollPane);
          frame.pack();
          frame.setVisible(true);

          for (int it=1; it<=cThreads; it++) {
            MyThread t = new MyThread(m_doc);
            t.start();
          }
        }
    });
    try {
      m_latch.await();
    }
    catch (InterruptedException ie) {
      ie.printStackTrace();
    }
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
          System.out.println("tf len: " + m_ta.getText().length());
          System.out.println("doc len: " + m_doc.getLength());
          System.exit(0);
        }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: +1 impressed by your tenacity :-) Though you lost me somewhere (my fault due to no real incentive to dig into this, not yours!) - typically, I simply make sure to access everything swing-related on the EDT and be happy. As for the caret: DefaultCaret has a property updatedPolicy (or similar, too lazy to search ... cough) which is good enough in most of the use-cases.

Comment: @Kleopatra, thanks! You reminded me about the important thing. What is it all for? **Efficiency**. Not impressive, these are the results (for 10000 loop, on Linux): work thread (like in the code above): **10s**, invokeLater: **15,5s**, invokeAndWait: 59,5s. `invokeLater` has only about 50% performance loss, so I'm with you! Side effect: EDT solutions update caret automatically.

Comment: re: scrolling to last line: you can get this done automatically for you; check out the default caret update policy here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/text/DefaultCaret.html#setUpdatePolicy-int-

Answer (score 2):

> `JTextArea` thread safe?

Definitely not. Not in general. As others stated even the `append` method is no longer documented to be thread safe. However [Java 7 documentaion of AbstractDocument.insertString](http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/javax/swing/text/AbstractDocument.html#insertString%28int,%20java.lang.String,%20javax.swing.text.AttributeSet%29) clearly states that this method is thread safe.

Using `AbstractDocument.insertString` seems to be safe according to docs. And that's the only reasonable option. Updating string model in gui thread would be a drastic performance loss.

How about `JTextArea.append`? I assume it depends on the underlying `Document`. For `PlainDocument` and `DefaultStyledDocument` it could be thread safe. For other models one should inspect the related documentation. If one does not know what is the underlying document, then they should treat `append` as not thread safe and call it only from EDT.

Edit: Another possible reason for `append` being not thread-safe: it consists of 2 operations: `getLength` and `insertString`, and between the 2, the contents of the document may change. So be careful also with constructs like `insertString(getLength(), ...)`. Without synchronization it's incorrect. `AbstractDocument.writeLock` may help, but it's protected.