# Dynamically adding text to a JTextArea using Java

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to add/append text to a `JTextArea` dynamically. I tried doing:

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
    jtextArea.append("i="+i);
    //some processing code***********
}
```

Actually all `i` values are appending to jtextarea after completion of `for` loop. But I want to add `i` value to jtextAres as `for` loop is progressing. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you are doing this on the *Event Dispatch Thread* and your processing code will block this thread. As a result, the `JTextArea` can not get repainted.

You need to get your processing code of the UI thread. The normal suggestion is to use a `SwingWorker`, but in this case it might be easier to just use a regular `Thread` and use `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` to schedule the `append` call on the EDT.

Note: I suggest calling `append` on the EDT as of JDK1.7 the javadoc of that method no longer states it is thread safe (the 1.6 javadoc still mentions this). But looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4869027/jtextarea-thread-safe) shows that even in 1.6 you are probably safer calling it on the EDT.

The [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) tutorial is a good read about this topic.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if I understand your question well, but try this code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    final int x = i;
    SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            jtextArea.append("i=" + x);
        }
    });

    //some processing code***********
}
```

Comment: In case the for loop is entered on the EDT (as I suspect since the updates are not visualized) this won't do a thing. Of course, if it is not on the EDT and he is using Java 7 where the append no longer seems thread safe this is a very good suggestion. We obviously need more info